# Identify from which QR code, request got originated

Tags: html, qr-code, web-deployment-project

I have 10 QR codes which point to a common webpage www.demoexp.com/index.html. How does this site knows that it is accessed from which of those 10 QR codes. My index.html needs to know the QR code from which request is originating.

Comment: Are you generating these QR codes yourself? If so, you can add an id to the url as parameter, i.e. www.demoexp.com/index.html?id=1. So all 10 will still point to same url but now you will know which QR code led you there because of each having own id.

Comment: Generating QR in https://www.the-qrcode-generator.com/

Comment: Yeah so instead of just putting your url in the textbox of this site, put url + some parameter as i described above. it will still lead to your site but with QR code's id appended. Example: www.demoexp.com/index.html?id=1 for 1st QR code, www.demoexp.com/index.html?id=2 for 2nd QR code and so on...

Comment: Thank you. Let me check and get back to you.